# Laravel sitemap result only one url

Tags: php, laravel, sitemap

I'm using Spatie\Sitemap

when I am using this -

```
SitemapGenerator::create('https://spatie.be/en')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
```

everything is fine all sitemap write correctly

But when I'm trying to my own server -

```
SitemapGenerator::create('https://localhost:90/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
```

it's only write one url
and in the console says **"Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)"** .
Is there something wrong with my script or in my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried http instead https http://localhost:90/ ?

Comment: yes I did, but the result still one url,

Answer (score 0):

Can You try without https i.e.

**instead of this**

`SitemapGenerator::create('https://localhost:90/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');`

**try this**

`SitemapGenerator::create('http://localhost:90/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');`

Comment: The Unsupproted SSL request is not showing, but the result still one url

Comment: As i read in the official github issues try checking whether crawler is enabled in ur localhost i have no much info how to check that.